# Powershell to get links off Box

Tags: powershell, hyperlink, box

We have a box account that contains vast numbers of files.  I need to get links to every item within a given folder - or at the very least those displayed on the current page.

However '(Invoke-WebRequest –Uri ‘http://web/address/place’).Links is giving me only links to the front page of box.com - not the address in the specific place I link to - which it probably can't access because it needs a login.  I imagine it's putting that address in, but with no login is simply taken to box.com

Comment: If the data you are after is not presented unless you log on, then PS can't get to it either unless you are passing that log on as well.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by link? Sharing, like https://app.box.com/s/ijvchvz0ptdxp....?

If so, I guess you first need to set it up for each file or folder. Second - you need to create developer account and use their API to do things like that.

But there is an easy way to interact with box account, at least to list/upload/download files because you can access it through FTP/FTPS. There are tons of example of how to ftp files (unsecure) with powershell. Below is a sample how to do it with FTPS (secure):

```
$url = "ftp://ftp.box.com"
$user = "youremail@yahoo.com"
$password = "yourpassword"

$client = [System.Net.FtpWebRequest]::Create($url)
$client.UsePassive = $true
$client.EnableSsl = $true
$client.Credentials = new-object System.Net.NetworkCredential($user, $password)
$client.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::ListDirectoryDetails

$res = $client.GetResponse()
$stream = $res.GetResponseStream()
$reader = [System.IO.StreamReader]::new($stream)
$reader.ReadToEnd()
```

This sample lists the files on the root directory. This way you can upload/download files as well